# Using non constant variables in a class

Tags: php, oop

I want to define a variable that won't be constant each time the class is called, but constant to use in my methods, so for example:

```
<?php

class ImageUploadModel
{

   public static $file_name = Session::get('id').'_'. md5("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz123456789") .'_'. uniqid();

   public static function blah()
   { 
        echo SELF::file_name; //I want it to be the same as function blah2
   }

   public static function blah2()
   { 
        echo SELF::file_name; //I want it to be the same as function blah
   }

//ended, so the next time it runs I want file_name to be a different value
```

I want every time it runs to be the same variable for each function, but when the class is called again to change value. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this, but generally speaking you'll need to generate the `file_name` before calling `blah` or `blah2`. (BTW, your md5 is always going to be the same value, which makes it pretty useless, imo. I would change what you hash or remove it entirely.)

```
<?php

public static function generateFilename ($id) {
    self::$file_name = $id . '_' . md5(time()) . '_' . uniqid();
}
```

Then to use it:

```
ImageUploadModel::generateFilename(Session::get('id'));
ImageUploadModel::blah();
ImageUploadModel::blah2();
```

and ImageUploadModel::$file_name will be the same between both "blah" calls.